# Why is my Python script too slow in comparison with Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm considering making the switch from Matlab to Python (NumPy). So, as a learning task, I have tried to rewrite a simple stochastic model on Python. The python script returns the right answer, but works too slow! It takes 3 minutes for Python instead 3 seconds like Matlab. What am I doing wrong?

Matlab:

```
clear all; clc;
tic

T = 0.05;
Tmax = 3600;
t = T:T:Tmax;
N = length(t);
G = [0 0;
    0 T];

F = [1 T;
    0 1];

Dksi = 13*1; 
Deta = 10*1; 
Band = 0.1:0.1:3;
RMS_Omega = nan(1, length(Band));
for i = 1:length(Band)
    K = nan(2, 1);
    K(1) = 8/3 * Band(i) * T; 
    K(2) = 32/9 * Band(i)^2 * T;

    ksi = sqrt(Dksi) * randn(1, N); 
    eta = sqrt(Deta) * randn(1, N); 

    Xest = [0; 0]; 
    Xextr = F*Xest;

    Xist = [0; 0];

    ErrOmega = nan(1, N); Omega = nan(1, N);
    for k = 1:N
        Xist = F*Xist + G*[0; ksi(k)];
        omega_meas = Xist(1) + eta(k);
        Xest = Xextr + K*(omega_meas - Xextr(1)); 
        Xextr = F*Xest; 
        ErrOmega(k) = Xest(1) - Xist(1); 
        Omega(k) = Xist(1);
    end

    RMS_Omega(i) = sqrt(mean(ErrOmega.^2));
end

figure(1)
hold on
plot(Band, RMS_Omega);
hold off
xlabel('Bandwidth, Hz'); ylabel('RMS \omega, Hz');
toc
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time as time


tbeg = time.time()

T = 0.005
Tmax = 3600.0

t = np.linspace(T, Tmax, int(Tmax/T))
N = len(t)

G = np.array([[0, 0],
              [0, T]])

F = np.array([[1, T],
              [0, 1]])

Dksi = 13.0
Deta = 10.0

Band = np.linspace(0.1, 3.0, 30)
Band_for_plot = 2

RMS_Omega = np.array([None for i in range(0, len(Band))])

for i, BW in enumerate(Band):
    K = np.array([[8/3 * BW * T],
                  [32/9 * BW*BW *T]])

    ksi = math.sqrt(Dksi) * np.random.randn(N)
    eta = math.sqrt(Deta) * np.random.randn(N)

    Xest = np.array([[0],
                     [0]])
    Xextr = F.dot(Xest)

    Xist = np.array([[0],
                     [0]])

    ErrOmega = np.array([None for j in range(0, N)])
    Omega    = np.array([None for j in range(0, N)])

    for k in range(0, N):
        Xist = F.dot(Xist) + G.dot(np.array([[0],
                                             [ksi[k]]]))
        omega_meas = Xist[0] + eta[k]
        Xest = Xextr + K * (omega_meas - Xextr[0])
        Xextr = F.dot(Xest)
        ErrOmega[k] = Xest[0] - Xist[0]
        Omega[k] = Xist[0]

    RMS_Omega[i] = math.sqrt(np.mean(ErrOmega**2))

elapsed = time.time() - tbeg
print(elapsed, u'sec')
```

Comment: Profiling your python script will show you the bottleneck.

Comment: You have huge native python loops. Those will be slow (comparatively). Numpy is not magic fairy dust, it will only speed up your code if you vectorize it.

Comment: yep 2 massive normal python loops, that's probably where you're slow, use numpy more

Comment: Well, for one thing, in Matlab `T = 0.05` but in Python `T = 0.005` - you are making Python work on 10x as much data.

Comment: Your MATLAB would be slow on older versions as well. The current MATLAB has some JIT compiling that lets you get away with loops.

Comment: @HughBothwell Thanks for your observation, it has reduced the time from 180 to 16 seconds

Comment: In addition to having the same `T` value, you can also make the nested for loop more efficient by using `xrange` instead of `range` cause with range you need to create a huge array in memory.
`for k in xrange(0, N):`

Comment: @saloua Thanks, it saves about 0.3 sec. There are 3.8 sec vs 16.2 sec for Matlab and Python correspondingly

Comment: np.empty(len(N)) may be better to initialise the ErrOmega and Omega arrays.

Comment: @IlyaKorogodin For the initialisation of the arrays ErrOmega and Omega you don't need to create an array of size N. Instead use `np.empty(N)` or `np.full(N, None)`.
`RMS_Omega` could also be initialised with `RMS_Omega = np.array(np.full(len(Band), None))`

Comment: @saloua, `xrange` no longer exists in Python3 (at least not in my 3.6.1 version)

Comment: Yeah I was talking about python 2.7. As @Ilya Korogodin did not mention the python version that he is using.

Answer (score 0):

Having dealt with similar issues, i learnt to avoid making the translation of codes. Despite it can save time in writing, it does not in the running (weight the usage/time of writing).

`for` loops in Python are normally slower than Matlab, but offers plenty of tools and libraries that can help to built a good code, so make use of them. The comments in the question are already a good help!